# NSIntegerMax vs NSUIntegerMax

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsinteger, nsuinteger

```
NSUInteger index = [self.objects indexOfObject:obj];

if (index == NSNotFound) {
    // Success! Note: NSNotFound internally uses NSIntegerMax
}

if (index == NSUIntegerMax) {
    // Fails!
}
```

Why? I'm suppose to get an unsigned value as a result of indexOfObject. So, naturally, i was assuming that if the object is not found, it will return NSUIntegerMax instead of NSIntegerMax. Is this a bug, or is there a logical explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps `NSNotFound` can be used in contexts that use `NSInteger`. It is also safer, in case someone declares index as `NSInteger` instead of `NSUInteger`.

At most, one could say that it's odd that `NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax`, but it's certainly not a bug.

Comment: See my reply to Eiko's post. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is just wrong. It returns an `NSNotFound`, *whatever* this is now or will be in the future. And it may easily be different on different platforms (i.e. 32 vs 64 bit).

The reason for its existence is to use it. Don't fool yourself with using other constants that *might* be the same.

Comment: Well, i believe my assumption was fair, though not accurate. Consider this... `[array count]` returns `NSUInteger`. Now, what if i have more than `NSIntegerMax` objects in array? It should allow more than NSIntegerMax values (though i haven't verified). Now if `NSIntegerMax` value returned by `[array indexOfObject:myObject]` is a valid value then a check for NSNotFound will/should fail. I must be missing something here.

Comment: @Mustafa: You can't have `NSIntegerMax` objects in an array, since this would consume about double the address space on a 32-bit architecture and about four times the address space on a 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Marcelo is right, check what you are comparing using the debugger. See my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970953/convert-nsinteger-to-nsuinteger/9422965

Answer (score 0):

An `NSUInteger` is unsigned (the 'U') while an `NSInteger` is signed.

You can still compare the values of an unsigned and a signed integer. Assuming that NSNotFound is actually equal to NSUIntegerMax is probably a mistake. In fact it is defined as equal to NSIntegerMax in NSObjCRuntime.h.

Comment: You misunderstood. I'm/I was assuming that indexOfObject will return NSUIntegerMax incase the object is not found, because it returns NSUInteger. I know that NSNotFound uses NSIntegerMax internally.